# API/Framework to generate Visual Studio solutions/projects

Tags: visual-studio, automation

Does anyone know of anything other than the Visual Studio automation API
 to use for generating Visual Studio Solutions and/or project files? The project files are MSBuild-based, so that should be OK to generate manually if I have to, but the solution files are based on a proprietary textual format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Tree surgeon](http://www.codeplex.com/treesurgeon) maybe? Although I don't think this is what you mean.

Comment: Thanks, that project looks interesting!